# How to set spark driver maxResultSize when in client mode in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, driver, pyspark

I know when you are in client mode in pyspark, you cannot set configurations in your script, because the JVM gets started as soon as the libraries are loaded.

So, the way to set the configurations is to actually go and edit the shell script that launches it:  `spark-env.sh`...according to this documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html).

If I want to change the maximum results size at the driver, I would normally do this: `spark.driver.maxResultSize`.  What is the equivalent to that in the  `spark-env.sh` file ?

Some of the environmental variables are easy to set, such as `SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY` is clearly the setting for `spark.driver.memory`, but what is the environmental variable for `spark.driver.maxResultSize`  ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration file is `conf/spark-default.conf`.

If `conf/spark-default.conf` does not exist

```
cp conf/spark-defaults.conf.template conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

Add configuration like

```
spark.driver.maxResultSize  2g
```

There are many configuration available, refer [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: After playing around with this parameter, it seems like it doesn't need to be set in the configuration settings.  I can actually be set in a python/java/scala script, because it isn't actually used until after the JVM is started.

Comment: do you mean use sc.getConf.set?

Comment: Yeah, like this: `conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g");`

Comment: However, `driver.memory` must be set in the `spark.defaults.conf` file, because that will affect it when the JVM is started.